# Всплывающее окно в форме

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

[image]

Подскажите, как можно такое реализовать? Есть форма и при нажатии кнопки нужно прикрепить всплывающее окно, где можно выбрать аватарку из представленных или выбрать файл и нажать кнопку "выбрать". 
Аватарки нужно сделать инпут радио? И как сделать, чтобы выбранный элемент вписался в главную форму путь аватарки (jquery)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Верстаешь блок, присваеваеш ему id и в стиль:

```
display:none;
```

> Потом по кнопке:

```
 display:block;
```

> И появится этот блок.

Answer (score 2):

`Ajax` с сылкой на файл, где лежат аватарки со своими `id` (можно `button`). Стили сам на все натянешь.